# Attempted to call function "curl_init" from namespace "Buzz\Client"

Tags: facebook, symfony, curl

I'm trying to set a facebook login (HWIOAuthBundle symfony2 ) but this is the error that i get 
Attempted to call function "curl_init" from namespace "Buzz\Client".
Any solution ?

Comment: Do you have the curl extension installed for PHP?  `<?php var_dump(extension_loaded('curl')); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Hi i've got the same problem and i found out that it was a problem after installing php7 on my server. 
My apache was still using php5 library and curl was remove for php5 and ok for php7. checkout the output of phpinfo() execute by the webserver