# Getting:" Attempted to call function "curl_init" from namespace", even though CURL is installed

Tags: php, apache, symfony-2.8

I am getting the error,

> Attempted to call function "curl_init" from namespace

but this is with curl installed and enabled.
The output from `php --ini` is as follows:

```
> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/5.6/cli Loaded
> Configuration File:         /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini Scan for
> additional .ini files in: /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d Additional .ini
> files parsed:      /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-gearman.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini, /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
```

I have even verified that it works by creating a curl request in a new file, and it worked!

This seems to be a problem specific to the Symfony, but I am reaching out to understand if I have missed out anything.

I am currently running Php 5.6.4, and the MVC framework is Symfony 2.8.

The procedure I have followed is

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
- sudo apt update
- sudo apt install php5.6-curl
- sudo service apache2 restart

This is the code

```
use CURLFile;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException;
use LogicException;       
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$ch  = curl_init($url);
```

Looking for any sort of help.

Comment: Do you have code? Probably need root namespace `$ch = \curl_init();`.

Comment: I think you have installed the curl lib in /etc/php/5.6/cli  in php CLI not in the php used by http server.

Comment: Could you please check if there is more than one php.ini in /etc/php/5.6... directory:   `find /etc/php -name php.ini `

Comment: @nourhero I did that, and the output is : /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini
So its only one PHP version I am currently running

Comment: this answer might give you hint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36900067/156869

Comment: @ariefbayu I had looked at that same answer before. It turns out I had 3 different versions of PHP running. I uninstalled each one except the 5.6 version. My php info file gives this PHP 5.6.40-21+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 as the php version. and Curl as 7.58 as its version. Also, the suggestion to run extension_loaded('curl') came out true. But a big thank you. :)

Comment: @AbraCadaver I tried as you suggested but it still didn't work. I have edited the question to show the code as well

Comment: There is two php configurations under your server :   
1) /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini 
2) /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini 
So you have to change configuration `/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini`  to activate the extention curl on php configuration `/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini` used by apache2 server

Comment: The way I did it was by, copying the CURL file from the cli folder to the extensions folder and it worked. It was missing the curl file